# If the subspace $W$ is $T$-invariant, then $W^\perp$ is $T^*$-invariant.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be **complex** inner product space and let $T$ be mapping from $V$ to $V$.
Prove that if the subspace $W$ is $T$-invariant, then $W^\perp$ is $T^*$-invariant.

I would like to ask if my proof is alright.
My proof:

If $W$ is $T$-invariant then we have that $T(w) \in W, \forall w \in W$, hence for $w \in W^\perp$:
$$\langle T(v), w\rangle = 0$$
$$\langle v, T^*(w) \rangle = 0, \forall v \in V$$
$\Rightarrow T^*(w) \in W^\perp \Rightarrow W^\perp$ is $T^*$-invariant. $\blacksquare$

I wonder if this is correct, and the fact that I did not use that V was a **complex** inner product is kind of worrying. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct. There is indeed nothing special about complex inner product spaces (compared to real inner product spaces) in this regard.

Comment: Thank you very much